# Preserve activity stack from notification click android

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

Here is the scenerio.
I am in the middle of my application.
Now I press home button and went to other application.

Now My applications GCM notification pop-ups.
When I click to that notification, it redirects me to desired activity.
Now when I click back from that notification activity, It should move to previous activity.

Here on back press of notification activity, I simply writes **finish()**

But here it exists the application.

my notification code,

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setContentTitle(from)
            .setContentText(body);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.gratzeez_logo_s_new);
    } else {
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.gratzeez_logo_s);
    }
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, ChatScreen.class);
    resultIntent.putExtra("receiverUserID",userID);
    resultIntent.putExtra("message",body);
    resultIntent.putExtra("SPName",from);
    resultIntent.putExtra("imageUrl",imgUrl);
    resultIntent.putExtra("fromNotificationClick",true);

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(ChatScreen.class);

    // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    mBuilder.setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.sound));
    mNotificationManager.notify(MESSAGE_NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
```